# Domain Driven Design (DDD) Common entity class with strongly typed Id

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, domain-driven-design

I see lots of DDD examples with something like following using Id of Guid type

```
    public abstract class Entity : IEquatable<Entity>
    {
        public Entity(Guid id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
        public Guid Id { get; private init; }
    }

    public class MyDomainClass : Entity 
    {
    }
```

I see other set of examples not using base abstract class but using a strongly type Id which derived from generic Id class.

```
    public class MyDomainClass
    {
        public MyId Id { get; private set; }

        public Location(MyId id, Currency currency)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }
   public class Id<T> 
    {
        protected T Value { get; private set; }
        protected Id(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();
        protected override object GetHashCodeComponents() => Value;
    }
   public class MyId : Id<string>
    {
        protected MyId(string value) : base(value) {
        }

    }
```

Can these both approaches be combined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with different implementation of generic Entity it is more simple and generic allows to have entities with different type of Id and comparable feature by Id,
Here is an example

```
public abstract class EntityWithTypedId<TId>
{

    public TId Id { get; set; }

    protected bool Equals(EntityWithTypedId<TId> other)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<TId>.Default.Equals(Id, other.Id);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((EntityWithTypedId<TId>)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return EqualityComparer<TId>.Default.GetHashCode(Id);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(EntityWithTypedId<TId> left, EntityWithTypedId<TId> right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EntityWithTypedId<TId> left, EntityWithTypedId<TId> right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

and then

```
public abstract class Entity : EntityWithTypedId<Guid>
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As for everything, DDD is very domain specific and there's no clear answer to that other than that: "It depends on your concrete problem domain".

In general people use uuids/guids als Id for several reasons (unique, can be sharded and merged w/o id conflicts) etc.

If you know that you are only going to use Guid, its fine to use a guid. Some domains don't even expose the Id property (= keep it private read-only field), because it usually a persistence concern any may leak persistence implementation into your domain.

Having a generic `Id<T>` class is questionable for this reason, because if you don't know that guid will be sufficient or you wanna use composed keys (by contacting multiple information to build a unique key, i.e. `Tenant-{tenantId}-User-{id}`), you can't really make a decision. If you do, then you already know if you need a string-based unique key or if a guid based key is sufficient enough.

As for having a typed Id, well in DDD its common to use these for value types and entity Id is a value type. It also prevents some misuse of your DDD API, i.e. a developer can't accidentally use `new Id(Guid.NewGuid())` or `new Id(someGuid)` where the id comes from an unverified source.

You could implement it in a away that the Guid is only created by the database layer or the entity itself. This results in the inability to create an `Id` type w/o loading an entity (read: You can only reuse existing Ids and not create new ones) which can (and will) increase maintainability of your DDD code.

Comment: you can enforce T to be of interface { Guid Id {get; set;}}. That way you still have guid as your backing Id but you make them stronly typed.